# Derivative of this equation

Tags: calculus

Our teacher gave us an assignment to find the derivative the equation given, but I have tried for more than 2 months, and yet can't get any way to do it. 
Are you guys willing to try?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}\right)=\frac{-8e^{4x}}{\left(e^{4x}-1\right)^2}$$

Comment: It would be better if you posted what you actually tried - i.e. list your steps. We can then help spot where you may have been making a mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you need the derivative of $$y=\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}$$ Multiply both numerator and denominator by $e^{2x}$; this gives you $$y=\frac{e^{4x}+1}{e^{4x}-1}$$ To make your life simpler, define $u=e^{4x}$ so $$y=\frac{u+1}{u-1}=\frac{u-1+2}{u-1}=1+\frac{2}{u-1}$$ and now apply $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thank you soo much you made the problem look like a child play could you just explain the step 2?

Comment: You are very welcome ! Many problems solve like that.